# PHP sentiment score of descriptions from CSV file

Tags: php, api, curl, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to get sentiment scores of random product descriptions from a CSV file, I'm facing a problem with what I think is the API response time, not sure if I'm traversing through the CSV using the API incorrectly / un-efficiently but it is taking a long time to get results for all the 300+ entries in the CSV and whenever I want to push new changes to my codebase I need to wait for the API to re-evaluate the entries every time, here is my code I made for loading in the CSV file and for getting the sentiment scores

```
    <?php

set_time_limit(500); // extended timeout due to slow / overwhelmed API response

function extract_file($csv) { // CSV to array function

    $file = fopen($csv, 'r');

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $lines[] = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ',');
    }

    fclose($file);
    return $lines;

}

$the_file = 'dataset.csv';
$csv_data = extract_file($the_file);



$response_array = []; // array container to hold returned sentiment values from among prduct descriptions

for($x = 1; $x < count($csv_data) - 1; $x++) { // loop through all descriptions
    echo $x; // show iteration
    $api_text = $csv_data[$x][1];
    $api_text = str_replace('&', ' and ', $api_text); // removing escape sequence characters, '&' breaks the api :)
    $api_text = str_replace(" ", "%20", $api_text); // serializing string
    $text = 'text=';
    $text .=$api_text; // serializing string further for the API
    //echo 'current text1: ', $api_text;
    $curl = curl_init(); // API request init

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://text-sentiment.p.rapidapi.com/analyze",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $text,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host: text-sentiment.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key: <snip>",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }


    $json = json_decode($response, true); // convert response to JSON format
    
    if(isset($json["pos"]) == false) { // catching response error 100, makes array faulty otherwise
        continue;
    }
    else {
        array_push($response_array, array($x, "+" => $json["pos"], "-" => $json["neg"])); // appends array with sentiment values at current index
    }
    
}

echo "<br>";
echo "<br> results: ";

echo "<p>";
for ($y = 0; $y < count($response_array); $y++){ // prints out all the sentiment values
    echo "<br>";
    echo print_r($response_array[$y]);
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "</p>";

echo "<br>the most negative description: ";
$max_neg = array_keys($response_array, max(array_column($response_array, '-')));
//$max_neg = max(array_column($response_array, '-'));
echo print_r($csv_data[$max_neg[0]]);

echo "<br>the most positive description: ";
$max_pos = array_keys($response_array, max(array_column($response_array, '+')));
echo print_r($csv_data[$max_pos[0]]);


?>
```

What this code snippet aims to do is find the most negative and most positive sentiment among the description column in the csv and print them out according to their index, I'm only interested in finding descriptions with the highest amount of positive and negative sentiment word number not the percentage of the overall sentiment

The file can be found in this [git repo](https://github.com/samiljimari/sentiment/blob/main/dataset.csv)

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Not sure what you expect from people.  You say you have 300 csv entries and thus you are making 300 curl calls to an external server.   If you want to get a better idea of this, you can utilize a timing class or roll your own.  I'm sure you'll see that this is limited by the response times of the api.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement a cache of some sort. When you say "new changes to my codebase", what do you mean?

Comment: Well as I wrote in the post, I expect a suggestion on how to get the data more efficiently rather than traversing through the array as I'm currently doing as obviously it's not a ideal way, thanks for your suggestion will take a look ath the timing class

Comment: @JacobMulquin probably, by that I mean, whenever I want to add a new print line or whatever really, I always need to do 300+ curl calls to get to see any changes I make and whether they work

Comment: how frequent will the data in csv change ?

Comment: @KenLee it will not change at all, the data is set to the existing CSV

Comment: reading data sequentially from a CSV takes time, will u consider using a db approach ?

Comment: Yes I could read the data from any source including a DB, do you think that could reduce the load time?

Comment: Honestly, this is not what SO is for.  It's for software engineering questions, and not suited to "make my design better" type questions.  Regarding @KenLee's comment, reading 300 lines from a static csv file on your server is not the bottleneck.  That likely happens in milliseconds.  The calls to the API are serialized.  People have brought up caching, and that makes sense if the return from the api doesn't change much or ever, but I doubt that is the case.  Curl will allow you to make multiple async calls.  See [curl_multi_init](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Comment: You didn't provide near enough information in your question as to what acceptable response time is, or how often you run this, or what you will do with the data, etc. Even if the data from the csv was in a database, it doesn't matter if you still have to do 300+ serialized calls to the external api.

Comment: @KenLee I don't thinks so.  Reading a CSV record is going to take µSeconds. An insignificant amount of time compared to a round trip HTTP request and response.

Comment: @gview Who says they must be serialized?

Comment: The code as written is serialized.  Nobody said it had to be.  In fact I provided a link to curl_multi_init which has the ability to do async built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a cache file.

This solution creates a file `cache.json` that contains the results from the API, using the product name as the key for each entry.

On subsequent calls, it will use the cache value if it exists.

```
set_time_limit(500);

function file_put_json($file, $data)
{
    $json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents($file, $json);
}

function file_get_json($file, $as_array=false)
{
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($file), $as_array);
}

function file_get_csv($file, $header_row=true)
{
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    
    if ($header_row === true)
        $header = fgetcsv($handle);

    $array = [];
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        if ($header_row === true) {
            $array[] = array_combine($header, array_map('trim', $row));
        } else {
            $array[] = array_map('trim', $row);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $array;
}

function call_sentiment_api($input)
{
    $text = 'text=' . $input;
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://text-sentiment.p.rapidapi.com/analyze",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $text,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host: text-sentiment.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key: <snip>",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        throw new Exception("cURL Error #:" . $err);
    }

    return $response;
}

$csv_data = file_get_csv('dataset.csv');

if (file_exists('cache.json')) {
    $cache_data = file_get_json('cache.json', true);
} else {
    $cache_data = [];
}

$cache_names = array_keys($cache_data);

$output = [];

foreach ($csv_data as $csv) {
    $product_name = $csv['name'];
    echo $product_name . '...';

    if (in_array($product_name, $cache_names)) {
        echo 'CACHED...' . PHP_EOL;

        continue;
    }

    $description = urlencode(str_replace('&', ' and ', $csv['description']));

    $response = call_sentiment_api($description);
    
    echo 'API...' . PHP_EOL;

    $json = json_decode($response, true);

    $cache_data[$product_name] = $json;
}

file_put_json('cache.json', $cache_data);

echo 'SAVE CACHE!' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$highest_pos = 0;
$highest_neg = 0;

$pos = [];
$neg = [];

foreach ($cache_data as $name => $cache) {
    if (!isset($cache['pos']) || !isset($cache['neg'])) {
        continue;
    }
    if ($cache['pos'] > $highest_pos) {
        $pos = [$name => $cache];
        $highest_pos = $cache['pos'];
    }
    if ($cache['pos'] === $highest_pos) {
        $pos[$name] = $cache;
    }
    if ($cache['neg'] > $highest_neg) {
        $neg = [$name => $cache];
        $highest_neg = $cache['neg'];
    }
    if ($cache['neg'] === $highest_neg) {
        $neg[$name] = $cache;
    }
}

echo "Most Positive Sentiment: " . $highest_pos . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($pos as $name => $pos_) {
    echo "\t" . $name . PHP_EOL;
}
echo PHP_EOL;

echo "Most Negative Sentiment: " . $highest_neg . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($neg as $name => $neg_) {
    echo "\t" . $name . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Results in:

```
Most Positive Sentiment: 4
        X-Grip Lifting Straps - GymBeam
        Beta Carotene - GymBeam
        Chelated Magnesium - GymBeam
        Creatine Crea7in - GymBeam
        L-carnitine 1000 mg - GymBeam - 20 tabs
        Resistance Band Set - GymBeam

Most Negative Sentiment: 2
        Calorie free Ketchup sauce 320 ml - GymBeam
        ReHydrate Hypotonic Drink 1000 ml - GymBeam
        Vitamin E 60 caps - GymBeam
        Vitamin B-Complex 120 tab - GymBeam
        Zero Syrup Hazelnut Choco 350 ml - GymBeam
        Bio Psyllium - GymBeam
        Zero calorie Vanilla Syrup - GymBeam
```

Comment: Nice code.  You appear to know more about this API than  me.  How does it reduce the curl request time?  That is, if the majority of the time, as I suspect, is in the `call_sentiment_api()` function.

Comment: It doesn't affect the curl request time at all, what it does is save the output from curl requests and then reads through that cache instead of doing the request. The OP said that the data would not change that often, so he could do a fresh run once a week or something like that. Once you run it once, it doesn't hit `call_sentiment_api` at all after that.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to know where the time is going.**

Start with identifying where the time goes in the curl request.
My guess is the API response time.

If that's the case I have a solution.  Meanwhile I will get the "multi-tasking" code code I use to do simultaneous curl requests.

curl has the timing you need.  It looks like this:

```
  'total_time' => 0.029867,
  'namelookup_time' => 0.000864,
  'connect_time' => 0.001659,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0.00988,
  'size_upload' => 0.0,
  'size_download' => 8300.0,
  'speed_download' => 277898.0,
  'speed_upload' => 0.0,
```

Just add a couple of lines of code

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$info = var_export(curl_getinfo($curl),true);
file_put_contents('timing.txt',$info,FILE_APPEND);
```

### Running simultaneous curl sockets.

Put your curl in curl.php

```
  $text = $_GET['text'];
  curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://text-sentiment.p.rapidapi.com/analyze",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $text,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host: text-sentiment.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key: <snip>",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
    ]);
```

This code goes in your CSV loop to create all the URL query fields to pass to curl.php (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/curl.php?text=$text`)

```
$query = urlencode($text);
$urls[] = array('host' => "127.0.0.1",'path' => "/curl.php?text=$query
```

Then process all the URLs.

```
  foreach($urls as $path){
    $host = $path['host'];
    $path = $path['path'];
    $http = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\n\r\n";
    $stream = stream_socket_client("$host:80", $errno,$errstr, 120,STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT); 
    if ($stream) {
      $sockets[] = $stream;  // supports multiple sockets
      fwrite($stream, $http);
    }
    else { 
      $err .=  "$id Failed<br>\n";
    }
  }
```

Then Monitor the sockets and retrieve the response from each socket.
Then close the socket until you have them all.

```
while (count($sockets)) {
  $read = $sockets; 
  stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, $timeout);
  if (count($read)) {
    foreach ($read as $r) { 
      $id = array_search($r, $sockets); 
      $data = fread($r, $buffer_size); 
      if (strlen($data) == 0) { 
     //   echo "$id Closed: " . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
        $closed[$id] = microtime(true);
        fclose($r); 
        unset($sockets[$id]);
      } 
      else {
        $results[$id] .= $data; 
      }
    }
  }
  else { 
 //   echo 'Timeout: ' . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
    break;
  }
}
```

**Then all your results are in `$results[]`.**

---